# Unable to run Springboot program " Unable to start web server; "

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, intellij-idea

refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat","context":"default"}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhFFW.png)

Comment: Please don't post the error as an image. Instead include the **full stacktrace** as properly formatted code so it is readable.

Comment: Please share pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your stacktrace, you should go down the `Caused by` chain. In your case, you will find a

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: brave/SpanCustomizer
```

This means the class `brave.SpanCustomizer` cannot be found. Check your setup:

- Maybe you missed a dependency?
- Or you made a spelling mistake?

PS: Please post the stacktrace as text, not as an image. You can edit your post to add the text now.